# Bootstrap MODAL action button not working

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, asp.net-mvc-5, bootstrap-modal

I work on MVC 5 with Bootstrap. My project have one modal,it’s open click on link, Bellow is my modal syntax,my problem is my footer action button is not working.Under the save button click event I want to **alert**.

target link:

### Heading

```
<a href="#" class="btn btn-lg btn-success"
   data-toggle="modal"
   data-target="#basicModal">Click to open Modal</a>
```

modal :

```
<div class="modal fade" id="basicModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="basicModal" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&amp;times;</button>
            <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Modal title</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <h3>Modal Body</h3>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" id="btnClose" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                <button type="button" id="btnSave" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
        </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

modal script:

```
@section Scripts {
    <script>
        $(function () {
            $('btnSave').on('click', function (event) {
                alert();
                event.preventDefault();
            });

        });

    </script>
}
```

Answer (score 4):

I recommend you to place you btnSave Jquery click event in Script Section of Layout.cshtml page . This click event must be placed after @Render body or it will best to place it exactly before  body Tag Ending

You Can Place the Following Code in Your Layout.cshtml as Below -

-- After @RenderBody

-1- First Load Jquery

-2- Then Load Bootstrap.min.js

-3-Then Place Bootstrap Model Html Code

```
<div class="modal fade" id="basicModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="basicModal" aria-hidden="true">
<div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&amp;times;</button>
        <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Modal title</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
            <h3>Modal Body</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="button" id="btnClose" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
            <button type="button" id="btnSave" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

-4- Then Place The Code Below

```
 <script>
    $(function () {
        $('#btnSave').on('click', function (event) {
            alert();
            event.preventDefault();
        });

    });

</script>
```

-5- Then Go to your View Where you want to place Button that will show popup and Place the code below

```
<a href="#" class="btn btn-lg btn-success"
   data-toggle="modal"
   data-target="#basicModal">Click to open Modal</a>
```

Answer (score 2):

You are on the right track, but without the `#`, it will try and look for elements with the tag name btnSave. You need to update your selector so that it will select an element with the ID btnSave:

```
$('#btnSave').on('click', function (event) {
    alert();
    event.preventDefault();
});
```

Comment: Cameron Tinker,thanks for reply.But it's not working for me.I used this modal as a partial view on my mvc5 project ,here click on btnSave not fire my alert.what to do?

Comment: Ah, you need to pre-load your JavaScript for your partial view. You can include the necessary JavaScript references in your view to load the modal's JavaScript. You could also use some sort of module loader like RequireJS to load your JavaScript on demand. Then, your code will execute when the partial is loaded.

Comment: Cameron Tinker, you are right my partial view page failed to load javascript portion.i am new in mvc, will you plz show me some syntax how to load javascript on demand or pre-load  javascript.thank you.

Comment: I have exactly the same issue, did you find any solution @shamim?

Answer (score 0):

Of course there is the possibility to simple use `onclick` to trigger save:

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="someAction();">Save changes</button>
```